# Powershell and IIS log files

Tags: powershell, iis

Hi I have 3 sets of server IIS file folders that need to be checked for unique visitors on a specific cs-uri-query field.

I've created a script as below but not sure if 1, how to iterate all log file from the 3 servers and  2, how to report on only unique users.

Any help appreciated.

```
$IISLogPath = "C:\iisTest\u_ex160123.log"
$IISLogFileRaw = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($IISLogPath) 
$headers = $IISLogFileRaw[3].split(" ") 
$headers = $headers | where {$_ -ne "#Fields:"}
$IISLogFileCSV = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Header $headers -Path $IISLogPath

$IISLogFileCSV = ($IISLogFileCSV | where {$_.("cs-uri-query") -match "IDA=21" -AND $_.("cs-username") -match "0#."}).count

Write-Host "Match in file" $IISLogFileCSV -f Yellow;
```

Comment: To iterate over the log files you can do 1) Copy all needed log files into a single directory the use Get-ChildItem to get a list to use in a for loop 2) Build an array of server paths then use Get-Child item to get list of files to iterate over. As for the unique users, each line should have a user as one of the fields, find the field, check if the value is in a list your keeping.

Comment: All 3 directories have files with the same names, is there a way around this?

Comment: Not powershell but have you considered using [LogParser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=24659)?
LogParser is a tool made by Microsoft that lets you run queries against log files like an SQL table.

The commands should be something like:
    logparser -i:IISW3C "select distinct cs-username from 'C:\<baselogpath>\*.log' where cs-uri-query like '%IDA=21%'" -recurse
or for outputting to a csv file you can use
    logparser -i:IISW3C -o:CSV "select distinct cs-username into '<path to output csv>' from 'C:\<baselogpath>\*.log' where cs-uri-query like '%IDA=21%'" -recurse

Comment: If you're going to copy the files, rename during the copy prefixing the server name.